# When I try to render my scene, the only thing that renders is the sky. BI

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have looked over every setting and checkbox I could think of that might be the cause of the issue (including render restriction and camera obstructions), and I'm starting to think it has something to do with memory, and not settings. Though if that were the issue, I expect there would be some kind of error message, based on some answers to questions other people had on related issues.

[Here is the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v8wjbptv8tPjacIco4Xj-LB0Z1N224lv)

The objects in front of the camera
[image: The objects in front of the camera]

The rendered image
[image: The rendered image]

Comment: So I downloaded your file and I can reproduce the problem. I confirm Cycles renders the image properly, but not BI.

Comment: Don't know what caused it, but this doesn't appear, if you past the whole thing into a new blender file. You still need to re-setup the sky and the camera dimensions, but it's a workaround.